# Omit categories from table

Tags: gtsummary

The following code

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(gtsummary)

df <- tibble(category = c("a", "a", "a", 
                    "b", "b", "b", "b"))

output_table <- df %>%
  tbl_summary()

output_table
```

produces this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7TXh.png).

Is it possible to remove the "a" category from this table without changing the associated frequencies? So in this case, the final table should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmXkw.png) (but without the extra whitespace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `tbl_summary(value=)` argument, you can select a single level of a categorical variable to display in the table.

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  select(grade) %>%
  # show only one level for grade
  tbl_summary(value = grade ~ "I", 
              label = grade ~ "Grade I")
```

[image]

You can also just delete a single row from the output. But you'll need to install the development version of the package to use the new function `modify_table_body()`.

```r
remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")
trial %>%
  select(grade) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  # remove grade I row
  modify_table_body(filter, !(variable == "grade" & label == "I"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess my example was too simple for what I actually want to do. In my real data, I have 3 categories, and I want to remove exactly one of them. Sorry for not being clearer in the original example, but I thought learning how to solve this would help me toward a solution, but unfortunately I am still stuck. Happy to make another reprex if it would help.

Comment: Update post with an additional solution that should get you what you're looking for